# Alamofire not sending upload-request (no connection established at all)

Tags: ios, swift, upload, alamofire

I want to upload a file, which has recently been downloaded (in my app) from the DocumentPicker (e.g. iCloud, Dropbox, ...)
So I have the NSUrl (`urlToFile`) of this file (verified)

I use this code to upload:

```
  upload(.POST, Config.uploadURL, urlToFile!)
    .progress { (bytesWritten, bytesWrittenInTotal, bytesToBeWritten) -> Void in
    println("Bytes: \(bytesWrittenInTotal)")
  }
  .responseString{(request, response, JSON, error) in
    println(request)
    println(response)
    println(JSON)}
```

There is no upload connection at all. The php-file which receives the upload has a log-feature, so every calling of the file gets logged. The code shown above never establishes a connection.

That's the output I receive:

> { URL: http://correctURLtoThePHPScript }
>
> nil
>
> nil

**Error Message:**

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Is a directory

I thought this is due to `documentPicker(controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAtURL url: NSURL)` returning the fileUrl with a trailing slash. But even if I remove that trailing slash via the code below, I get the same error message!

```
let s = url.URLString
let strippedUrl = s.substringToIndex(advance(s.startIndex, count(s)-1))
urlToFile = NSURL(string: strippedUrl)
```

Solution:
use `urlToFile = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: strippedUrl)`!!

Comment: Please, print out error parameter so we can debug this code. Also: `Config.uploadURL` is correct, right?

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. The error is: _Error: Optional(Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=21 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Is a directory" UserInfo=0x7fd3b261b9d0 {_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=21, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1})_

Comment: Looks like the URL to your file really is a URL to a directory?

Comment: Well kind of. The return value from the DocumentPicker is a `NSUrl` with the complete filePath plus the fileName but with a closing */* character! I need to get rid of that, keeping a valid NSUrl

Comment: LOL! Always print / use NSError data: it's the only way Alamofire can "talk" to you

Comment: =) Actually I thought I did print the error and it was nil. How can I get rid of the trailing / ?

Comment: `let s: NSString = "/path/to/my/file/" as NSString

s.substringToIndex(s.length-1)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up all comments:

- always print out / listen to `NSError` values returned from Alamofire (or Core Data, or anything else). The only way they can communicate back to your code is through these errors
- the problem was that a file path ended in a path separator, i.e. `/path/to/my/file.txt/`
- to remove the offending `/` at the end:

```swift
let s: NSString = "/path/to/my/file/" as NSString
s.substringToIndex(s.length-1)
```

Comment: Thank you again. I implemented this now, but I still get the same error ! I updated my question to give more information